# Drawing regression line on image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, linear-regression

I have this image:

[image: Altered Image]

I used OpenCV functions such as sobel and erode on this original image to generate the one you see above:
[image: Original Image]

The image is a frame from a live camera inside a boiler. In this boiler, there is an ash pile and the line that can be seen in the first image is that ash pile. I want to be able to automatically generate a regression line where the straight line can be seen, for example:

[image: Regression]

I am not sure what I need to do to achieve this and the solution needs to be able to pick up on different kinds of lines, as it might not always be in the same spot or the same length etc. I have attempted to draw contours, but as you can see in the original image there is not enough contrast to truly pick up the ash pile.

Comment: [I can only repeat myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72709860/finding-contours-in-a-video-with-a-lot-of-noise). the ash pile is *just not there*. you can't [fix this with image processing](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FixItInPost). you have to fix how the pictures are taken. -- for that specific image (and no other image), you could mask away the noisy upper part and try to fit a line through the stronger edges in the bottom right... but that's not robust at all because you say you need this to work in different environments.

Comment: your camera seems to pick up thermal infrared along with whatever can be seen in the visible spectrum. consider optical filters (physical ones) to select useful spectra

Comment: The input image is very difficult to process. You need to change the mode of capturing images